# Rxjs manipulate data several time from the initial source

Tags: rxjs

I have an Observable and I want to manipulate the data two times from the same source without modify the data for the next one.

I mean if I use two times .map() the first one modify data and the second one get the modified data. i don't want that.

Sorry, for sure I can find the answer in StackOverflow, but I don't find it with my words and I don't understand schemas from Rxjs doc.

**UPDATE**

```
this.anObservable
  .map((data) => { 
      // Here we manipulate and save formatted data in variable 'resume'
      this.resume = this.doSomething(data) 
  })
  // Here I want to send data to another function, but that send the formatted data and not de initial data
  .map((data) => this.doOtherThing(data));
```

Same with :

```
this.anObservable
  .map((data) => { 
      this.resume = this.doSomething(data);
      this.doOtherThing(data);
  })
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
/** This doesn't work : */

this.anObservable
      .do((data) => { 
          // Here we manipulate and save formatted data in variable 'resume'
          this.resume = this.doSomething(data) 
      })
      // Here I want to send data to another function, but that send the formatted data and not de initial data
      .map((data) => this.doOtherThing(data));
```

I also tried with variable :

```
private dataToFormat;

this.anObservable
      .do((data) => {
          this.dataToFormat = data;

          // let dataToFormat = data;
          this.resume = this.doSomething(this.dataToFormat) 
      })
      // Here I want to send data to another function, but that send the formatted data and not de initial data
      .map((data) => this.doOtherThing(data));
```

**UPDATE 3**

I have a service :

```
  // Sources
    private formData = new Subject<any>();
    // Streams
    public formData$ = this.formData.asObservable();

    public setData (request: any): void {
        this.formData.next(this.removeEmptyObjectsAndFormatDate(request));
    }
```

Then I subscribe to it :

```
 this.service.formData$
          .do((data) => {
              this.resume = this.doSomething(data) 
          })
          // Here I want to send data to another function, but that send the formatted data and not de initial data
          .map((data) => this.doOtherThing(data));
```

Nobody has the answer ?

Comment: probably giving an explicit example will help us understand your requirements

Comment: @CozyAzure I've updated my question. Hope you understand what I want to do.

Comment: use `.do()` instead of `.map()`

Comment: I already try with `.do()` but I get an Observable and not the data from the initiate Observable

Comment: -_- Sorry, It's working, If I use `.do()` after `.map()` I get an observable, before I get the data.

Comment: @CozyAzure AAA no it' doesn't work actually, I always get the formatted data in my second function...

Comment: I have written an answer addressing this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156840/discussion-between-swarovski-and-cozyazure).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.do()` if you just want to do something and not transforming the data. In reactive programming, that is what we called "no side effect".

However, do note that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, and hence any manipulation to the object will in fact, manipulated the object. What you want to do is create a shallow copy of it, and then manipulate it, and then save it.

You can easily achieve this via `Object.assign()` method:

```js
this.anObservable
    .do((data) => {
        let newCopyOfData = Object.assign({}, data);
        this.resume = this.doSomething(newCopyOfData);
    })
    // the data here wont get changed
    .map((data) => this.doOtherThing(data));
```

Comment: :S no the data passed to map is the formatted data from .do();

Comment: Maybe because my Observable is an instance of Subject : 
    `// Sources
    private formData = new Subject<any>();
    // Streams
    public formData$ = this.formData.asObservable();`